C program never ends stuck in a for loop
I made a simple program to perform Galois Finite Field Multiplication but somehow the program is stuck in a loop.
#include<stdio.h>

int GaloisMult(int a, int b){
    int i,j=0,h=0,k,abits[8],bbits[8];
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        if(((a >> i) & 1) == 1) abits[j++] = i;
        if(((b >> i) & 1) == 1) bbits[h++] = i;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < j; i++) printf("%d ",abits[i]);
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < h; i++) printf("%d ",bbits[i]);

    int dbits[11] = {0};

//here
    for (k = 0; k < h; k++) {
        for (i = 0; i < j; i++){
            int index = abits[i] + bbits[k];
            dbits[index] = (dbits[index] + 1) % 2;
        }
    }

    int val = 0;
    for (i = 10; i >= 0; i--) val = (val << 1) | dbits[i];
    while(val > 0xff) val ^= 0x11b;
    return val;
}

int main(){
    int a = 0xac;
    int b = 0x0e;
    printf("\n%02X * %02X = %02X",a,b,GaloisMult(a,b));
}

the program never ends somehow stuck in the 2d for loop.

I actually observe that it gets stick here: while(val > 0xff) val ^= 0x11b; (because val stays bigger than 0xff). Do you use a debugger ? You can also add a printf for val inside the loop to help debug it.

yeah it gets stuck here may be the problem is how the xor is performed. i might have to add my own xor logic because the 2nd variable has to align with MSB of 1st variable to reduce the number otherwise they alternate between 2 values and never actually gets reduced.

Also, using XOR on a signed int is nonsense most of the time. Anything >-1 XOR whatever will result in a value <= -1.

Please see what happens when I limit h to 10.   ( h=10; )   I notice when this line is commented out, looping seems to go forever.

So the problem was not with the for loop but with the XOR logic in the While loop.
the Galois Field XOR calculation goes like this, suppose we have 2 variables
11010001000 and 100011011. then we have to perform the XOR until the resulting bits has no 1 above 8th position.
11010001000
100011011
-----------
01011100100

the result has 1 in the 10th position so we XOR that with the 2nd variable again but this time we remove the leading 0.
1011100100
100011011
----------
0011010010

this time the result has no 1 above 8th position so this is the final result we want.
the problem with doing XOR like result = a ^ b will do
11010001000
  100011011
-----------
11110010011

which doesn't work.
the  correct logic i implemented is this
#include<stdio.h>

int intFromBits(int bits[]){
    int val = 0,i;
    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) val = (val << 1) | bits[i];
    return val;
}

void xor(int d[15],int c[15],int* r){
    int i=0,j=0;
    while(d[i++] != 1) j++;
    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) r[i] = d[i] ^ c[(i-j+15) % 15];
}

int GaloisMult(int a, int b){
    int i,j=0,h=0,k,abits[8],bbits[8],dbits[15] = {0},cons[] = {1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        if(((a >> i) & 1) == 1) abits[j++] = i;
        if(((b >> i) & 1) == 1) bbits[h++] = i;
    }
    for (k = 0; k < h; k++) for (i = 0; i < j; i++) dbits[14 - (abits[i] + bbits[k])] = (dbits[14 - (abits[i] + bbits[k])] + 1) % 2;
    while(intFromBits(dbits) > 0xFF) xor(dbits,cons,dbits);

    return intFromBits(dbits);
}

int main(){
    int a = 0xff;
    int b = 0xff;
    printf("\n%02X * %02X = %02X",a,b,GaloisMult(a,b));
}

the custom XOR function shifts the 2nd variable to adjust the trailing and leading 0s to perform the correct XOR logic required to do Galois Multiplication XOR.
Note: this GaloisMult only works for 2^8 Fields.

The loop that the program gets stuck is not in the for loop, but actually in the while loop:
while(val > 0xff) val ^= 0x11b;

In this line, you are doing an XOR assignment. The XOR operation has a self-inversion property, so every time you do val ^ 0x11b = result, it means that in the next iteration, result ^ 0x11b = val, so it will be endless.
Check out this line, reassess your stop condition, and analyze what you want to do in your code.
Hope it helps!

I don't think that's exactly the issue. It's just that any bits of val above bit 8 will always be unaffected by the xor, because those bits in 0x11b are all zero.

Hi Jer, I actually ran the code debugging it. When the code reaches the while, val is equal to 0x688. and then when it does have the XOR with 0x11b it becomes 0x793, and then 0x793 is XOR with 0x11b and turns back to 0x688. You could easily verify it by changing:
while(val > 0xff) val ^= 0x11b;
to:
while(val > 0xff) { val ^= 0x11b; printf("actual val: %02x\n", val);}

@FelipeNovais Check my answer i explained why it doesn't work and how did i solved it.

@FelipeNovais, I don't think Jeremy was disagreeing about where the program was getting stuck, but rather about your characterization of the problem in terms of xor being its own inverse (which we all agree it is).  That means the OP is wrong to loop over the xor operation, but a more significant issue is that if the loop condition is satisfied in the first place then the xor-based update being performed cannot change that even on the first iteration.  It seems to be altogether the wrong computation to perform.

@jaimin-vashi I'm glad to know you solved it :)

@john-bollinger Looking from this perspective, I totally agree. Thank you so much for the clarification.

@FelipeNovais John is correct. The bits above bit 8 are left untouched on every iteration and provided val is not negative, it will always be greater than 0xff. If you want to test this for yourself, try xor'ing val with a bit pattern that has the top bit set (i.e. any bit pattern that is negative). You'll find that, on each alternate iteration, val becomes negative and hence less than 0xff.
